# simplemodal window positioning on ipad

Tags: jquery, cycle, simplemodal, scrolltop

I'm just finishing some work on a project viewer that presents a nested jQuery Cycle widget within a SimpleModal window. It's working very well, except that now I'm trying to debug a few things for iPad.

Take a look a the graphic below for a better idea of what's happening, but basically SimpleModal seems to have trouble with the way mobile safari returns scrolltop or it's equivalents. I know the SimpleModal 'position' option needs to be updated, I'm just now sure how to best go about it.

[image]

Comment: This problem seems to affect all JQuery modal plugins I've found, except FaceBox.

Comment: Hey cool I just checked it out and you're right, FaceBox works just fine on my iPad. When I get a few minutes I'm going to dissect fb and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use "fixed" option:

$(element).modal({fixed: false}); Proof - https://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/issues/detail?id=80

My code

```
 $.modal(data, {
                        minWidth: 350,
                        maxWidth: 400,
                        maxHeight: 450,
                        autoResize: false,
                        overlayClose: false,
                        fixed: false,
                        opacity: 80,
                        onShow: runPopup
                    });
```